# Laravel treat pivot table as model with relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, pivot

I am new to laravel and still a little bit confused about relations.

I have two models: Tournament and Season with many to many relations.

```
Schema::table('tournaments', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
});

Schema::table('seasons', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
});
```

and the pivot table

```
Schema::table('season_tournament', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('season_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('tournament_id')->unsigned();
    $table->primary(['season_id','tournament_id']);
});
```

And relations described in Models like

```
//Tournament model
public function seasons()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Season');
}

//Season model
public function tournaments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tournament');
}
```

And everything works perfect until I need to add a new model - Event, with next relations:
Any tournament in any season can have separate events. So each season_tournament record can have many events, and each event should belongs to exact season_tournament record. So when I run the next code:

```
Tournament::first()->seasons()->latest()->first()->events;
```

I should not get all events from the whole season, but from pair tournament_season.

So basically it looks like I need extended pivot with 3 columns like:

```
Schema::table('event_season_tournament', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('event_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('season_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('tournament_id')->unsigned();
    $table->primary(['event_id','season_id','tournament_id']);
});
```

Is there any built-in methods to manage such things? Or maybe there are more simple solutions?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a `event_season_id` column in your events table?  That way you don't have to make changes to the pivot table or previous relations?  In this case, it would be appropriate to create an `EventSeason` model which would be a model for your pivot table.  You'd also probably want to change the primary key to `id` and you can add a unique key for `season_id` and `tournament_id` just to keep the uniqueness enforced.